marginaleffects R package: correct syntax for predictions function using map
I am trying to compute predictions using the R::marginaleffects package. I would like to do this several times for specific predictor variables of interest, within a map / apply like function, but am struggling to get the syntax right. My attempt is:
pred_list <- map(list("var1 = 1:10", "var2=21:30"), \(x) predictions(my_model, newdata = datagrid(!!x)))

However, this does not give me a list of predictions for each of var1 and var2, across the specified ranges, with other predictors in the model held at default values.
Any help would be much appreciated.

You are much more likely to receive a useful answer if you provide a reproducible example. E.g. use my_model <- lm(qsec ~ hp + am, data = mtcars), and rewrite your map call to suit that.

You can use do.call() to feed arguments to the datagrid() function. Note that you need to specify the model object explicitly because of scoping issues:
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + wt, data = mtcars)

args <- list(list(wt = 1:3, model = mod), list(hp=100:103, model = mod))

lapply(args, function(x) predictions(mod, newdata = do.call(datagrid, x)))
> [[1]]
> 
>  wt Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)     S 2.5 % 97.5 %  hp
>   1     28.7      1.476 19.4   <0.001 277.2  25.8   31.6 147
>   2     24.8      0.896 27.7   <0.001 557.8  23.1   26.6 147
>   3     20.9      0.479 43.7   <0.001   Inf  20.0   21.9 147
> 
> Columns: rowid, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, hp, wt, mpg 
> Type:  response 
> 
> 
> [[2]]
> 
>   hp Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)     S 2.5 % 97.5 %   wt
>  100     21.6      0.623 34.6   <0.001 871.0  20.4   22.8 3.22
>  101     21.5      0.617 34.9   <0.001 885.5  20.3   22.8 3.22
>  102     21.5      0.611 35.2   <0.001 900.3  20.3   22.7 3.22
>  103     21.5      0.605 35.5   <0.001 915.2  20.3   22.7 3.22
> 
> Columns: rowid, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, wt, hp, mpg 
> Type:  response

